# Space between framedtext boxes in a column

Tags: spacing, context, framed, vertical

I have a problem with **framedtexts**. What I want to achieve are framedtext boxes laying one below another, so the vertical distance between them is always the same (I want it to be zero, so there is no space between them). I can achieve it only when framedtexts have the same heights. When I have a few kind of framedtexts with different heights, then the space between them is not the same.

It is funny, because some time ago I manage to achieve the desired result, but now the same tex files give invalid output. Currently I am working with ConTeXt Process Management 1.04 - current version: 2021.03.05 19:11

Could anyone tell me please what I need to change in my code so I can get equally spaced framedtext boxes?

Here is minimal code fragment that shows the undesired behavior.

```
\language[pl]
\enableregime[utf8]
\setuppapersize[A4,portrait][A4,portrait]% -- 210 mm x 297 mm
\setuplayout[
  backspace=15mm,
  topspace=2mm,
  width=190mm,
  height=294mm,
  headerdistance=0mm,
  footer=0mm,
  footerdistance=0mm,
  location=singlesided,
]

\newdimen\taskheight
\taskheight=35.3mm

\defineframedtext[taskA][
    width=\textwidth,
    height=1\taskheight,
    framecolor=gray,
    offset=1mm,
    frameoffset=0pt,
    backgroundoffset=frame,
    location=none,
    linecorrection=on,
    depthcorrectiopn=off,
    after={\vskip-24pt},
]

\defineframedtext[taskB][taskA][
    height=2\taskheight,
]

\defineframedtext[taskC][taskA][
    height=3\taskheight,
]

\defineframedtext[taskD][taskA][
    height=4\taskheight
]

% ===

\startcomponent test
\chapter{name}
\startcolumns[n=2,balance=no]

\starttaskD
df
\stoptaskD

\starttaskA
df
\stoptaskA

\starttaskC
df
\stoptaskC

\starttaskA
df
\stoptaskA

\starttaskB
df
\stoptaskB

\stopcolumns

\stopcomponent
```

Comment: What if you set `\taskheight` to, say, `5\lineheight`?

Comment: @mickep It seems that defining the value of `\taskheight` as a multiple of `\lineheight` resolves my issues! However, `location` must be changed to `location=,` or `location=top`, otherwise you can't control distance between boxes, which I define by `after={\vskip-24pt}`. Thank you very much! I just wonder - do anybody know why I need to use `\lineheight` and what is the role of `location` parameter?

Comment: Could it be that `\lineheight` is good since the columns work on a grid? I don't know about the location, though.

Comment: The columns environment uses grid mode, to disable it and prevent extra vertical space bwteen lines add `grid=no` to `\startcolumns`. Even when you do this you get a small space between the frame which is added by TeX, the value for this space is stored in the `\lineskip` register. To get rid of this skip you can either add `\nointerlineskip` between each frame or you disable it with `\setupinterlinespace[off]`. To ensure the setting is local to the columns environment put the settings in a setups block (`\startsetups [...] ... \stopsetups`) and load it with `\startcolumns[setups=...]`.

Comment: @WolfgangSchuster I really appreciate you in-depth answer. Now it is clear to me how to deal with `\startcolumns` environment. I think that I have never get upon any article about the machanism lying behind column layout, nor I have never met the `grid` option. Thank you once more for great explanation.